# What is expr[{ ... }] for?

Tags: c++

[This page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access) on cppreference says:

> **Built-in subscript operator**
> The subscript operator expressions have the form
>
> *expr1* **[** *expr2* **]**   (1)
> *expr1* **[ {** *expr, ...* **} ]**   (2) (C++11)
>
> …
> 2) The form with brace-enclosed list inside the square brackets is only used to call an overloaded `operator[]`

Other than this, there's no example or explanation of what it means to use braces inside operator[].

On godbolt.org I verified that, given `S s;`, `s[{3}]` can be used to call a custom `S::operator[](int)`, while if we had `S s[5];` then `s[{3}]` would be invalid. However, it doesn't seem to work for multiple arguments i.e. `s[{3, 4}]` (Clang's error mentions the argument is treated as an initializer list).

So...what's the point of this feature? When would I want to use `[{}]` instead of just plain `[]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its purpose is to allow initialization of any argument type from a brace-init-list. It's added in C++11 to go along with the new initialization syntax, where braces were allowed as initializers for all types (as opposed to just for aggregates).

An example

```
std::map<std::pair<int, int>, double> m {
 // content
};

// later

m[{1, 2}] = 2; // {1, 2} initializes a std::pair which is then used for sub-scripting.
```

Since a `{ ... }` is not an expression under the C++ grammar, we can't use `{}` in the production `[ expr2 ]`. An explicit grammar rule was needed.

Comment: If {} isn’t an expression, then how does it work in function call arguments, and rhs of assignments? Do all these have special cases in the grammar? And...why isn’t it an expression? :)

Comment: @jtbandes: "*Do all these have special cases in the grammar?*" Yes. Every one of them. "*And...why isn’t it an expression?*" That is a very complex question that probably could even be answered by a specific SO Q&A. The shortest version would probably be that a naked `{}` is meant to mean "initialize an object of a type inferred by its usage". The usage of `{}` as a generalized term in an expression however would often lead to confusion as to exactly what type it will initialize. Like, what type should `{1, 3} + 2` deduce to, and why should it deduce to that?

Comment: @jtbandes: By contrast, `m[{1, 2}]` is much easier to trace: figure out what type `m` is, track down its `operator[]` overload(s) and look at the parameter in the set to see what the possibilities are. Cases like `{1, 3} + 2` would be much easier to understand if you explicitly used a typename to initialize. `Vec2D{1, 3} + 1` is immediately comprehensible. And while `{1, 3}` is not an expression, `Vec2D{1, 3}` is.

Comment: Why don't we need the same rule for `operator()`? Cpprefence [lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_function_call_operator) only this rule: `E ( A1, A2, A3, ... )`. What is the difference between `E[A]` and `E(A)`?

Comment: @Evg - We do need it. But cppreference is not the standard. You'd need to follow the [grammar production](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.post#1) to see where the adjustment is done.